# nHibernate - SaveOrUpdate (no persistor for:)

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, c#-4.0

I have an Abstract class:

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class BaseModel
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public virtual string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    public virtual string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
}

public enum Status
{
    InActive = 0,
    Active = 1
}
```

and i have a class:

```
public class Page : BaseModel
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Route { get; set; }
    public virtual string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Parent { get; set; }
}
```

When i run the following code i get an error:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            DataAccess.McContext.Save(new Models.Page() { Name = "Home" + i, Parent = "0", DisplayName = "Home", Route = "Home", Status = Models.Status.Active });
        }
```

The Error Accurs here:

```
    public static void Save(object obj)
    {
        Session.SaveOrUpdate(obj); // Error: No persister for: MVCms.Models.Page
    }
```

I am using Fluent nHibernate and i have automappings on.

Can anyone tell me wtf i am doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nhibernate says that you have no mappings for MVCms.Models.Page. Try checking configuration and [export all generated mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036270/generate-xml-mappings-from-fluent-nhibernate) into files.

Comment: Thanx, i had another class in that assembly that was not supposed to be included in the automappings. Everything working prrrrrrfect now.