# IIS Idle Time-out and NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-4, fluent-nhibernate

I'm developing a MVC4 application with NHibernate. In my computer it works great, but when I deploy my application on my shared hosting provider I noticed that NHibernate starts all over again every 40 minutes. NHibernate must start just once, when the App starts, it takes about 10 minutes to initialize.

After trying to solve the problem, I discovered that the problem is with the host server because its Idle Time-out is 40 minutes, and I can't change this time! How can I fix it ? I already tryed to use a Timer or another thread to perform some action and tryed this website too http://www.uptimerobot.com to ping my site every 5 minutes. But none of this seems to work..

Comment: 10 minutes? Ugh... Maybe save the raw NHibernate mappings that come out of Fluent NHibernate to a file as a cache and then load them on start if the file is available, instead of re-creating everything from scratch?

Comment: Huum, How can I do that ? I didn't even know it was possible

Comment: Check out [this link](http://entron.wordpress.com/2010/01/06/optimizing-application-startup-time-with-fluent-nhibernate-and-unhaddins/) or [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036270/generate-xml-mappings-from-fluent-nhibernate), unfortunately I don't have my own code available at this very moment. After you export the mappings, should be fairly easy to check if the file exists and load them.

Comment: I serialized the Configuration object, but its still slow because the delay is in BuildSessionFactory method. Can I serialize somehow my Configuration so BuildSessionFactory loads faster ? Obs: I'm using XML mapping files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the time goes in initializing SessionFactory class, I would suggest you serialize it into a file when you first initialize it, then keep loading it and Deserialize it back on application start.

You'll have to clear the file, if you modify your db though.

Comment: I serialized the Configuration object, but its still slow because the delay is in BuildSessionFactory method. Can I serialize somehow my Configuration so BuildSessionFactory loads faster ?

Comment: Obs: I'm using XML mapping files

Comment: You can check this blog post for details:
http://lucisferre.net/2009/06/18/speed-up-nhibernate-startup-with-object-serialization/

Comment: It worked, Thank you!!! I was tryed this article, but it didnt worked because I was using a XML configuration file, not fluent config. Thank you! But do you why it is so much faster than config with XML file ? It was taking about 10 minutes, now its taking about 4 seconds!

Comment: I found the problem. I was using `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>` in my XML configuration file. Thats why it was so slow to build section factory! I removed this property and it is so fast as fluent!