# Is this valid way to convert fluent nhibernate to xml?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to convert this code:

```
Component(x => x.User, x =>
        {
            x.References(m => m.UserAccount).Columns(@"UserAccountId", @"UserAccountType");
            x.References(m => m.Postman, @"PostmanId");
        });
```

back into hbm.xml, my question: is everything alrigh with way I did it or am I missing something?
Converted code:

```
<component name="User">
  <many-to-one name="UserAccount">
    <column name="UserAccountId"/>
    <column name="UserAccountType"/>
  </many-to-one>
  <many-to-one name="Postman" column="PostmanId"></many-to-one>
</component>
```

Comment: After hours of investigation I found out I was digging in a wrong direction, I simply missed one mapping, but my PC couldn't evaluate function result in debug, it caused timeout with <component>.
If any even, this mapping is correctly translated back to nhibernate from fluent-nhibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can output all of your fluent nhibernate mappings as xml if you want.  Sounds a lot easier than this.

[Generate XML mappings from fluent Nhibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036270/generate-xml-mappings-from-fluent-nhibernate)